# Write GeoLocation Twitter4J to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, geolocation, twitter4j, akka-stream

I am extracting tweets using Twitter4J and Akka Streams. I have chosen a few fields like userId, tweetId, tweet text and so on. This Tweet entity gets written to the database:

```
class Counter extends StatusAdapter with Databases{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TweetsExtractor")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  implicit val LoggingAdapter =
    Logging(system, classOf[Counter])

  val overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure
  val bufferSize = 1000
  val statusSource = Source.queue[Status](
    bufferSize,
    overflowStrategy
  )

  val insertFlow: Flow[Status, Tweet, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Status].map(status => Tweet(status.getId, status.getUser.getId, status.getText, status.getLang,
      status.getFavoriteCount, status.getRetweetCount))
  val insertSink: Sink[Tweet, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(tweetRepository.create)
  val insertGraph = statusSource via insertFlow to insertSink
  val queueInsert = insertGraph.run()

  override def onStatus(status: Status) = 
    Await.result(queueInsert.offer(status), Duration.Inf)
}
```

My intention is to add location field. There is a specific GeoLocation type for that in Twitter4J which contains latitude and longitude of double type. However, when I try to extract latitude and longitude directly through the flow nothing is written to the database:

```
Flow[Status].map(status => Tweet(status.getId, status.getUser.getId, status.getText, status.getLang, status.getFavoriteCount, status.getRetweetCount, status.getGeoLocation.getLatitude, status.getGeoLocation.getLongitude))
```

What may be the reason of such behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably stupid question: did you check that the `GeoLocation` field has some value for the tweets you wanted to save? It's not mandatory and it makes sense that it doesn't have any value.

Comment: @stefanobaghino it's not a stupid question, you actually helped me to find a solution to the problem. As I understand not many tweets are posted with location and I get them in real-time so I need to wait for a long time for such tweets or choose some other parameter like User location, if I need too. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good, I posted this as an answer, I would appreciate if you could mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here, as confirmed in the comments to the question, is that most tweets do not come with geolocation data attached, making those fields empty and resulting in the misbehavior.

A couple of simple checks for empty values should solve the issue.